# Is "neugierig" the temporary desire or the life-long characteristic?

Tags: meaning, adjective

My dictionary translates "curious (inquisitive)" to "neugierig". There are two kinds of inquisitive curiosity, though: the temporary, pressing desire to find something out, and the long-term characteristic to seek knowledge.

Does "neugierig" fit as a translation in both of the following examples?

> Please tell me! I'm so curious.
>
> Bob has been reading Wikipedia for hours. He's a very curious boy.

Which kind of curiosity is understood in this example?

> -- Ich habe dir ein Phykologiebuch gekauft.  
> -- Was für ein Buch? Ich bin so neugierig!

Comment: Danke, @bernd und @pekka.

Comment: Do you study biologie? If not, you rarely know the word _Phykologie_ and speak of _ein Buch über Algen_. I had to look it up. http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phykologie

Comment: Do you mean the "Was für ein Buch" in the sense "I have no idea what _Phykologie_ is"? Then _to me_, "Ich bin so neugierig" sounds a bit awkward; I'd rather say "Jetzt bin ich aber neugierig".

Comment: @bernd: I think this is by intention; see my previous comment `:-)`

Comment: When speaking, make sure you spell *Phykologie*. ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Does "neugierig" fit as a translation in both of the following examples?

It does. [Leo](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&lang=de&searchLoc=0&cmpType=relaxed&sectHdr=on&spellToler=&search=neugierig)'s translations have the full bandwidth:

- curious  adj.
- inquiring esp AE / enquiring esp BE  adj.
- inquisitive  adj.
- nosy   also: nosey  adj.
- prying  adj.
- snoopy  adj.

"Neugierig" fits for all of these. In some contexts, it *can* carry a slightly negative connotation (when used like "nosey"/"prying"), but it doesn't by default.

The most fitting translation for "inquisitive" (which is more of a life-long characteristic) is ["wissbegierig"](http://dict.leo.org/ende?lp=ende&p=CqhggsWkAA&search=wissbegierig&trestr=0x8004) (Literally, "greedy/eager for knowledge", but with no negative connotation at all.)

Comment: Thanks. In the latter example, is it understood that the speaker is curious about the book or curious about things in general?

Comment: @Tim it is crystal clear that the speaker is curious about the book, like in the english example.

Comment: +1 for _wissbegierig_.

Comment: Ein Alternative ist auch *wissensdurstig*

Answer (score 4):

It is used for both:

As a temporary attitude towards a specific thing/event:

> Die ganze, wochenlange Geheimnistuerei
>   hat mich neugierig gemacht.

As a personality trait:

> Er war immer schon ein neugieriger
>   Mensch.

The personality trait 'openness' of the so called [big 5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_Five_personality_traits) includes to a certain extent curiosity. The big 5 are known to be very stable personality factors (traits).

Answer (score 2):

"Neugierig," unlike many other adjectives, is not "time limited." Instead, it's strictly "qualitative." That means in can be used to refer either a temporary or lifelong want.

It is often translated as "curious," but it's literal meaning is "eager for the new."